# Can I emulate a NAS OS on Windows 7 with an extra network adpter?

Tags: windows-7, raid, nas, emulator

I want to setup a RAID NAS but I don't want to buy another computer or lose the game library of my Windows i7 system.

Therefore, I'm wondering if you could just use an emulator to run a NAS OS in the background using a separate LAN card (or two) to go to the router.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly: Yes, you can emulate a NAS OS in Windows 7.

1. Download and install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
2. Download the [FreeNAS ISO](http://www.freenas.org/download-releases.html)
3. Create a new Linux virtual machine in VirtualBox
4. Mount the ISO in VirtualBox as a CD-ROM and start the VM

You can connect with a host-only virtual ethernet adapter so you don't need another networking card. As far as getting it configured or having it read from a hard-drive, I will leave you to figure it out.

Comment: thanks for the help may have bought vmware although would be nice to have a more passive option then a virtual box

Comment: There are tricks to run virtual box totally in the background.